# Converting from 1 joint PDF to another

Tags: calculus, probability

I have a question here on joint pdf. Given $M$ and $N$ have such a joint pdf:

$$
f_{M,N}(m, n) = 
\begin{cases}
2 &\text{ for } 0<n<m<1
\\0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Find the joint pdf of $A=M$ and $B=M+N$?

I know for a fact that I need to draw the triangle above and resolve $M$ and $N$ in terms of $A$ and $B$, resulting in

$$
\begin{align*}
M &= A\\
N &= B-A
\end{align*}
$$

After which, I am not sure how to proceed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the general change of variable formula
$$
 f_{A,B}(a,b) = f_{M,N}(m,n) \Big|\frac{\partial(m,n)}{\partial (a,b)}\Big|
$$
where $m = a$ and $n = b-a$ and the second factor above is the determinant of the Jacobian of the transformation $(a,b) \mapsto (m,n)$. (Hint: for your example that determinant is constant.)

Be sure to write the density in a format including the limits. For example
$$
  f_{M,N}(m,n) = 2\times 1\{ 0 < n < m < 1\}
$$
where $1\{\cdot\}$ is $1$ if whatever condition inside holds, otherwise zero. This way, when you substitute $m = a$ and $n = b-a$, you can read where the new density is zero.